# Substract value with previus value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am making app in vue.js and right now I have a little problem

```
async fetchCovidDataByDay(){
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${this.name}/status/confirmed`);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.arrConfirmed= [];
    this.arrDeaths = [];
    this.arrRecovered = [];
    this.arrActive = [];

    data.forEach(item =>{
      const date = moment(item.Date).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
      const {
        Confirmed,
        Deaths,
        Recovered,
        Active
      } = item;
      this.arrConfirmed.push({date, total: Confirmed})
      this.arrDeaths.push({date, total: Deaths})
      this.arrRecovered.push({date, total: Recovered})
      this.arrActive.push({date, total: Active})
    })
    return data;
  },
```

so my total should be Confirmed[i] - Confirmed[i-1] :)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @derpirscher Like i said i try to make my total Confirmed[i] - Confirmed[i-1], 
i try to i++ for each but it returns Nan, i also try 

```somevar += this.arrConfirmed[this.arrConfirmed.length-1].total```
but still not working

Comment: I don't see any  variable `i` in your code

Comment: @derpirscher it`s okay

Comment: Please provide some input data and the expected output from this data, as this would make it alot easier to understand, what you actually trying to do. And please update the code in your question, to the actual code you have tried and is not working ...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-worker-41pnh6?file=/src/components/CountrySelect.vue here is sandbox so i i have total value of active cases, but i need to calculate for 1 day, so idea is to calulate previus day with day like previus date was 100 and "today" is 120, so today value should be 100 - 120 = 20

Comment: I think I understand better now - edited my answer @JanJi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the forEach to

```
data.forEach((item, i) =>{
```

You can access the previous item like so

```
  this.arrConfirmed.push({date, total: Confirmed - (data[i - 1]?.Confirmed || 0)})
```

`?.Confirmed || 0` is purely for index 0, when there is no previous item

```js
const data = [{Confirmed: 100}, {Confirmed: 120}, {Confirmed: 180}, {Confirmed: 300}];
const arrConfirmed= [];
let prevConfirmed = 0;
data.forEach((item, i) =>{
    const { Confirmed, } = item;
    arrConfirmed.push({total: Confirmed - (data[i - 1]?.Confirmed || 0)});
});
console.log(arrConfirmed);
```

Comment: i think this solved problem but still have wrong value at first member but i will figure it out :)

Comment: the first member should be whatever it is, as there is nothing to subtract since there's nothing before

Comment: true my brain is just out :D

Comment: @JanJi - don't worry, my first attempt to answer was so laughable because my brain was out too